# How does return statement work in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Consider these functions

```
f1 :: Maybe Int
f1 = return 1

f2 :: [Int]
f2 = return 1
```

Both have the same statement `return 1`. But the results are different. `f1` gives value `Just 1` and `f2` gives value `[1]`

Looks like Haskell invokes two different versions of `return` based on return type. I like to know more about this kind of function invocation. Is there a name for this feature in programming languages?

Comment: It is not a statement...

Comment: `return` works entirely differently in Haskell than it does it different languages. Pretend it's not even called `return`. `inject` would probably be a slightly better name to think of it as.

Comment: To start, I suggest starting ghci and typing `:t return`. (You may need to import the correct module first.) This will give you some information about its type that can give you some clues about how it works.

Comment: `return` is actually just a simple function in Haskell. It does *not* return something. It wraps a value into a monad.

Comment: Also, you should study about type classes. The `Monad` type class is used here.

Comment: Further, a function doesn't need any special return statement in Haskell. The return value of a function is simply the value computed by the body of the function. Note that neither `f1` nor `f2` is a function at all; they are simply values, as a function by definition takes exactly one argument.

Comment: This can be called class polymorphism or sometimes ad-hoc polymorphism (although truly ad-hoc classes are generally discouraged).

Comment: Looks like return is an overloaded function. Normally a function is overloaded  based on type of function argument, But in this case it is overloaded based on return type.

Comment: @shajen Haskell doesn't have overloaded functions. It has polymorphic functions. It's similar to implementing an interface in OO languages.

Comment: @shajen "in this case it is overloaded based on return type" This is sometimes called "return-type polymorphism" https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/105662/is-return-type-only-polymorphism-in-haskell-a-good-thing A simpler example of it is `mempty` for the `Monoid` typeclass.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Or simply use `pure` instead of inventing `inject`, since `pure` already exists and is a (more powerful) synonym of `return`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Going to agree with amalloy here. It's not always an injection anyway (`Proxy` provides a counterexample).

Comment: @amalloy That's fair. I used Inject because I was trying to think of a word while walking, and Inject was used in an article I read years ago on the topic.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a long meandering answer!

As you've probably seen from the comments and Thomas's excellent (but very technical) answer You've asked a very hard question.  Well done!

Rather than try to explain the technical answer I've tried to give you a broad overview of what Haskell does behind the scenes without diving into technical detail. Hopefully it will help you to get a big picture view of what's going on.

`return` is an example of *type inference*.

Most modern languages have some notion of polymorphism.  For example `var x = 1 + 1` will set `x` equal to 2. In a statically typed language 2 will usually be an int. If you say `var y = 1.0 + 1.0` then `y` will be a float.  The operator `+` (which is just a function with a special syntax)

Most imperative languages, especially object oriented languages, can only do type inference one way.  Every variable has a fixed type.  When you call a function it looks at the types of the argument and chooses a version of that function that fits the types (or complains if it can't find one).

When you assign the result of a function to a variable the variable already has a type and if it doesn't agree with the type of the return value you get an error.

So in an imperative language the "flow" of type deduction follows time in your program Deduce the type of a variable, do something with it and deduce the type of the result.  In a dynamically typed language (such as Python or javascript) the type of a variable is not assigned until the value of the variable is computed (which is why there don't seem to be types).  In a statically typed language the types are worked out ahead of time (by the compiler) but the logic is the same. The compiler  works out what the types of variables are going to be, but it does so by following the logic of the program in the same way as the program runs.

In Haskell the type inference also follows the logic of the program. Being Haskell it does so in a very mathematically pure way (called System F). The language of types (that is the rules by which types are deduced) are similar to Haskell itself.

Now remember Haskell is a lazy language.  It doesn't work out the value of anything until it needs it. That's why it makes sense in Haskell to have infinite data structures. It never occurs to Haskell that a data structure is infinite because it doesn't bother to work it out until it needs to.

Now all that lazy magic happens at the type level too. In the same way that Haskell doesn't work out what the value of an expression is until it really needs to, Haskell doesn't work out what the type of an expression is until it really needs to.

Consider this function

```
func (x : y : rest) = (x,y) : func rest
func _ = []
```

If you ask Haskell for the type of this function it has a look at the definition, sees `[]` and `:` and deduces that it's working with lists. But it never needs to look at the types of x and y, it just knows that they have to be the same because they end up in the same list. So it deduces the type of the function as `[a] -> [a]` where a is a type that it hasn't bothered to work out yet.

So far no magic. But it's useful to notice the difference between this idea and how it would be done in an OO language.  Haskell doesn't convert the arguments to Object, do it's thing and then convert back. Haskell just hasn't been asked explicitly what the type of the list is. So it doesn't care.

Now try typing the following into ghci

```
maxBound - length ""
maxBound : "Hello"
```

Now what just happened !?  minBound bust be a Char because I put it on the front of a string and it must be an integer because I added it to 0 and got a number. Plus the two values are clearly very different.

So what is the type of minBound? Let's ask ghci!

```
:type minBound
minBound :: Bounded a => a
```

AAargh! what does that mean?  Basically it means that it hasn't bothered to work out exactly what `a` is, but is has to be `Bounded` if you type `:info Bounded` you get three useful lines

```
class Bounded a where
  minBound :: a
  maxBound :: a
```

and a lot of less useful lines

So if `a` is `Bounded` there are values minBound and maxBound of type `a`. 
In fact under the hood `Bounded` is just a value, it's "type" is a record with fields minBound and maxBound. Because it's a value Haskell doesn't look at it until it really needs to.

So I appear to have meandered somewhere in the region of the answer to your question.  Before we move onto `return`  (which you may have noticed from the comments is a wonderfully complex beast.) let's look at `read`.

ghci again

```
read "42" + 7
read "'H'" : "ello"
length (read "[1,2,3]")
```

and hopefully you won't be too surprised to find that there are definitions

```
read :: Read a => String -> a
class Read where
  read :: String -> a
```

so `Read a` is just a record containing a single value which is a function `String -> a`.  Its very tempting to assume that there is one read function which looks at a string, works out what type is contained in the string and returns that type. But it does the opposite. It completely ignores the string until it's needed.  When the value is needed, Haskell first works out what type it's expecting, once it's done that it goes and gets the appropriate version of the read function and combines it with the string.

now consider something slightly more complex

```
readList :: Read a => [String] -> a
readList strs = map read strs
```

under the hood readList actually takes two arguments
    readList' (Read a) -> [String] -> [a]
    readList' {read = f} strs = map f strs

Again as Haskell is lazy it only bothers looking at the arguments when it's needs to find out the return value, at that point it knows what `a` is, so the compiler can go and fine the right version of Read. Until then it doesn't care.

Hopefully that's given you a bit of an idea of what's happening and why Haskell can "overload" on the return type. But it's important to remember it's not overloading in the conventional sense. Every function has only one definition. It's just that one of the arguments is a bag of functions. `read_str` doesn't ever know what types it's dealing with. It just knows it gets a function `String -> a` and some Strings, to do the application it just passes the arguments to `map`. `map` in turn doesn't even know it gets strings. When you get deeper into Haskell it becomes very important that functions don't know very much about the types they're dealing with.

Now let's look at `return`.

Remember how I said that the type system in Haskell was very similar to Haskell itself. Remember that in Haskell functions are just ordinary values. 
Does this mean I can have a type that takes a type as an argument and returns another type?  Of course it does!

You've seen some type functions `Maybe` takes a type `a` and returns another type which can either be `Just a` or `Nothing`.  `[]` takes a type `a` and returns a list of `a`s. Type functions in Haskell are usually containers. For example I could define a type function `BinaryTree` which stores a load of `a`'s in a tree like structure. There are of course lots of much stranger ones.

So, if these type functions are similar to ordinary types I can have a typeclass that contains type functions.  One such typeclass is `Monad`

```
class Monad m where
  return a -> m a
  (>>=) m a (a -> m b) -> m b
```

so here `m` is some type function. If I want to define `Monad` for `m` I need to define `return` and the scary looking operator below it (which is called bind)

As others have pointed out the `return` is a really misleading name for a fairly boring function. The team that designed Haskell have since realised their mistake and they're genuinely sorry about it. `return` is just an ordinary function that takes an argument and returns a `Monad` with that type in it. (You never asked what a Monad actually is so I'm not going to tell you)

Let's define `Monad` for `m = Maybe`!
First I need to define `return`. What should `return x` be? Remember I'm only allowed to define the function once, so I can't look at `x` because I don't know what type it is. I could always return `Nothing`, but that seems a waste of a perfectly good function.  Let's define `return x = Just x` because that's literally the only other thing I can do.

What about the scary bind thing? what can we say about `x >>= f`? well `x` is a `Maybe a` of some unknown type `a` and `f` is a function that takes an `a` and returns a `Maybe b`. Somehow I need to combine these to get a Maybe b`

So I need to define `Nothing >== f`. I can't call `f` because it needs an argument of type `a` and I don't have a value of type `a` I don't even know what 'a' is. I've only got one choice which is to define

```
Nothing >== f = Nothing
```

What about `Just x >>= f`? Well I know `x` is of type `a` and `f` takes `a` as an argument, so I can set `y = f a` and deduce that `y` is of type `b`. Now I need to make a `Maybe b` and I've got a `b` so ...

Just x >>= f = Just (f x)

So I've got a `Monad`!  what if `m` is `List`?  well I can follow a similar sort of logic and define

```
return x = [x]
[] >>= f = []
(x : xs) >>= a = f x ++ (xs >>= f)
```

Hooray another `Monad`!  It's a nice exercise to go through the steps and convince yourself that there's no other sensible way of defining this.

So what happens when I call `return 1`?

Nothing!

Haskell's Lazy remember.  The *thunk* `return 1` (technical term) just sits there until someone needs the value. As soon as Haskell needs the value it know what type the value should be. In particular it can deduce that `m` is `List`. Now that it knows that Haskell can find the instance of `Monad` for `List`. As soon as it does that it has access to the correct version of return.

So finally Haskell is ready To call return, which in this case returns [1]!

Comment: So Haskell applies two things in this situation. First it does a type deduction and then look for a Monad that has the 'return' implemented for that type. I guess same thing is happening in these examples too:  fromJust (return 1)  and  head (return 1). Thanks for the explanation. Thomas's answer explained how there is multiple versions of 'return'

Answer (score 7):

The `return` function is from the Monad class:

```
class Applicative m => Monad (m :: * -> *) where
  ...
  return :: a -> m a
```

So return takes any value of type `a` and results in a value of type `m a`.  The monad, `m`, as you've observed is polymorphic using the Haskell type class `Monad` for ad hoc polymorphism.

At this point you probably realize `return` is not an good, intuitive, name.  It's not even a built in function or a statement like in many other languages.  In fact a better-named and identically-operating function exists - `pure`. In almost all cases `return = pure`.

That is, the function `return` is the same as the function `pure` (from the Applicative class) - I often think to myself "this monadic value is purely the underlying `a`" and I try to use pure instead of return if there isn't already a convention in the codebase.

You can use `return` (or pure) for any type that is a class of `Monad`.  This includes the Maybe monad to get a value of type `Maybe a`:

```
instance Monad Maybe where
...
    return      = pure  -- which is from Applicative

...
instance Applicative Maybe where
    pure = Just
```

Or for the list monad to get a value of `[a]`:

```
instance Applicative [] where
    {-# INLINE pure #-}
    pure x    = [x]
```

Or, as a more complex example, Aeson's parse monad to get a value of type `Parser a`:

```
instance Applicative Parser where
    pure a = Parser $ \_path _kf ks -> ks a
```